# Add an annotation value to select_related

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'd like to add an annotation to a field that I fetch with `select_related`. I know that you can do that with `prefetch_related` like this:

```
vote_qs = Vote.objects.annotate(my_count=Count('some_related_objects'))
queryset = MyModel.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('votes', queryset=vote_qs)
)
```

What I like to do is something like

```
user_qs = User.objects.annotate(my_count=Count('some_related_objects'))
queryset = MyModel.objects.select_related(
    Select('user', queryset=user_qs)
)
```

Django doesn't support that. But how can I do that and avoid raw SQL as far as possible? (I couldn't find any information via Google.)

To clarify, this might be a workaround but then I can't do another filter or something anymore:

```
queryset = list(
    MyModel.objects
    .annotate(my_count=Count('user__some_related_objects'))
    .select_related('user')
)
for obj in queryset:
    obj.user.my_count = obj.my_count
```

Comment: Counting a field in a queryset does not makes much sense, since then the queryset just "folds" to a single row.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, I tried to make it more clear.